# Comparing different references (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop a question-answer app. Firebase database looks like this:

```
-users
    -userId
        -answers
            -questionId : answer
            -questionId : answer

-questions
    -questionId
    -questionId
    -questionId
    -questionId
```

If a user answers a question, that question is stored under answers section according to userId. My problem is to find an unanswered question by the user and show it on the activity. To do this, first, I pick a question from `questions` list then check if it exists in `answers` list. This is the method:

```
public void showUnansweredQuestion()
{
    questionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot question: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                final String questionId = question.getKey().toString();

                usersRef.child(user.getUid())
                        .child("answers")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(questionId))
                                {
                                    updateUI(questionId);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

However, this methos always shows the last unanswered question while I want to see the first one. Problem is probably the for loop, I cannot write `break` in if or cannot define a flag because of the inner class. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to make an empty `ArrayList` right at the start of your `showUnansweredQuestion()` method. Then instead of calling `updateUI()` in your inner `onDataChange()`, you could add the relevant questionId's to the ArrayList. When you're finished iterating over the questions (so you have a full list of all the unanswered ones), you can call `updateUI()` on the first one in the ArrayList.